# Pycharm wont display certain .html views by web2py

Tags: python, html, pycharm, web2py

I have a file layout.html in my Pycharm projects folder which Pycharm is unable to display. The "Loading..." screen never finishes. Most other .html views work fine.

web2py uses the syntax / delimiters such as {{ }} to inject python code into html and I think this might be the source of the problem. But this works with most files, therefore it might be a special case. ( {{try blocks or {{# comment blocks maybe?)

File can be displayed fine in other editors, I suspect a linting issue but I am unable to fix it. Is anyone familiar with this problem and knows a solution?

Comment: Could you please send `idea.log` from **Help | Show Log in ...** to pycharm-support@jetbrains.com? And `layout.html` as well if you can share it. Seems like an issue with parsing in PyCharm. The logs are probably full of exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the contact, I'll update this question if I hear from them. Problem is definitely reproducible as the log contained multiple similar context whenever I tried to open the file